# Drag&Drop ListBox Items out of the LisBox Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a sample data bounded to the listbox datatemplate and each item has a MouseDragElementBehavior with ConstrainToParentBounds false. I want to dragging any item in the listbox to any space in the page. However, Items are still bounded to the Listbox. Any Suggestions? AllowDrop property does not work on Windows Phone.

```
<ListBox x:Name="countryName"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="361" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <el:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="False"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">

                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: you want that if u drag that item from list then it should not remain in list ?? or can u please explain ur question ...\

Comment: It does not matter for now, I need to drag & drop any listbox item in anywhere on the screen, not just inside the listbox such as reordering.

Comment: @ErduranKorkut Have you found a solution for this by now?